# CountDownTimer Android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, timeunit

I am trying to countdown to an event in android. the date and time for the event is stored in the database, but the Countdown returns more days than it should.

This is what have tried.

```
String EventDate="2013-12-26 15:00:00";

SimpleDateFormat FormatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",Locale.US);
FormatDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));

try {
    Date date = FormatDate.parse(mm);


    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
Long ToCount=date.getTime();
CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(ToCount, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        EventTv.setText(""+ String.format(
        "%d Days,%d Hours, %d min, %d sec",
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))

        ));


    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EventTv.setText("done");

    }
}.start();
```

But if I run the app, the TextView shows `(16059days,3875429hours,23125799min)`.

Please help me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: getTime() returns the milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970. You likely want to do ToCount = date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMilis(); providing date > current time.

Comment: @dymmeh Thanks, i changed it but now i get (4days 97hours 5878min 41sec). With EventDate Set to ="2013-12-23 20:00:00";

Comment: Well, today is the 19th.. so that makes sense to me.

Comment: Realize that you're using millisUntilFinished for each one. So 97 hours = 4 days. 5878min = 4 days.. etc.

Comment: Okay,Thanks. I get it now.. Please how do i convert each one?

Comment: @olakunle Check my answer for how to convert them.

Comment: @JamesG Thanks.. I'd try your code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```
date.getTime()
```

It is returning the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970, midnight GMT.

So to get the number of milliseconds from the current time you would need to use

```
Date now = new Date();
Long ToCount = date.getTime() - now.getTime();
```

Also to convert the millisUntilFinished to the relevant format you would want to use

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished) -
TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished)),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) -  
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Worked perfectly.  I Really appreciate